# fontFamily attribute not working via textAppearance

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fonts

I have next style:

```
 <style name="Text.Light">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans_light</item>
    </style>
```

If I set it to `TextView` in xml via `textAppearance` like `android:textAppearance="@style/Text.Italic"` in design time it shows italic font, but in runtime it doesn't affect. But, if use fontFamily directly in TextView like `android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_italic"` it works perfect in both cases (design and runtime).
What am I doing wrong? There is my font-family xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <font
        android:font="@font/open_sans_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/open_sans_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/open_sans_italic"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/open_sans_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
</font-family>
```

Comment: currently, your style in the question is `open_sans_light`. I just test and see that font italic still working well, can you share your font, and which device, API you testing

Comment: @PhanVanLinh thank you for your answer. I found where problem was. I choose textViewStyle in my AppTheme and there was fontFamily. According to documentation textAppearance has minimum priority and it can't override other styles which defined in theme or anywhere else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was I choose `textViewStyle` in my `AppTheme` and there was `fontFamily`. According to [post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d) `textAppearance` has minimum priority and it can't override other styles which defined in theme or anywhere else.